# Azure Grab Data from Blob Storage w. Python (No downloading)

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to open a series of different cracked documents / texts that we've stored in Azure Blob storage, ideally pushing them all into a pandas db. I do not want to download them (I'm going to be opening them from a Docker Container), I just want to store the information in memory.

The file structure looks like: Azure Blob Storage -> MyContainer -> UUIDFolderNames (many) -> 1 "knowledge.json" file in each Folder.

What I've got working:

```
container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string( <my connection str>, <MyContainer> )
blob_list = container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    blobClient = container.get_blob_client( blob ) #Not sure this is needed
```

Ideally for each item in my for loop, I'd do something like opening the .json file, then adding it's text to a row in my dataframe. However, I can't actually manage to open any of the JSON files.

What I've tried:

```
#1
name = blob.name 
json.loads( name )

#2
with open(name, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load( f )
```

Errors:

#1 Json Decoder Error Expecting Value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

#2: No such file or directory

I've tried other sillier things like json.loads( blob ) or json.loads('knowledge.json') (no folder name in path), but those are kinda nonsensicle things that I was just trying to see if they worked, they're not exactly reasonable.

Most methods (including on Azure's documentation) download the file first, but again, I don't want to download the file.

*Edit: I realized that its somewhat obvious why the file's cannot be found - json.load etc will look in my local directory / where I'm running the python file from, rather than the blob location. Still, not sure how to load a file w.o downloading it.

Comment: You can't just open an Azure Storage blob as a file, as it's not a file and there is no file-handling, aside from downloading, or opening as a stream. If you want to work with blobs as files, you need to use a File share instead (which provides SMB support). Blob storage has no compute component, so unless you download (or stream) your content to where your code is, there's really no way to work with it.

Comment: Does streaming require downloading? Looking into it now, the example or two I've seen do include downloading the streamed info. I assume from what you said about the ~structure / purpose of Azure blob storage, the answer is yes downloading is still required

Comment: Yes, streaming would essentially be downloading to wherever your app's code is running (though not necessarily writing to disk). There's really no way around this, aside from using a tool to just copy content between storage containers, for example. I'm not quite sure what your concern is, around this: if you have your storage in the same region as your compute, the data movement speed is incredibly fast, and there are no bandwidth egress charges.

Answer (score -2):

With the help of the below block you will be able to view the JSON blob:

```
for  blobs  in  container_client.list_blobs():
    blob_client = service_client.get_blob_client(container=Container_name, blob=blobs)
    content = blob_client.download_blob()
    contentastext = content.readall()
    print(contentastext)
```

Below is the full code to read JSON files from blobs, later you can add this data to your dataframes:

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient,PublicAccess
import  os
import  logging
import  sys
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  azure.storage  import  blob
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

def  UploadFiles():
    CONNECTION_STRING="ENTER_CONNECTION_STR"    
    Container_name="gatherblobs"    
    service_client=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)    
    container_client = service_client.get_container_client(Container_name)

    for  blobs  in  container_client.list_blobs():
        blob_client = service_client.get_blob_client(container=Container_name, blob=blobs)
        content = blob_client.download_blob()
        contentastext = content.readall()
        print(contentastext)

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    UploadFiles()
```

Comment: You're writing a lot of code that isn't related to the OP's question. In fact, you're doing exactly what the OP didn't want to do: download content (via `download_blob()`). Yes, that really is a correct way to do things but... that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Basically what David said. I'm explicitly looking to Not use the "download_blob()" command.

Comment: I check ot 2024 now, still don't have any way to ignore download_blob, I'm thinking about remote api to help that.